# $1<2^b-3^a<100$ for very large numbers

Tags: number-theory

are there any known extremely large numbers, for $a$ and $b$ in the billions or trillions, where the difference between the two powers $2^b-3^a$ ist very small. I know that it will never be $1$ but maybe any other small integer?

I feel like there should be but if I run it on my computer the difference never really seems to dip below a certain threshold (e.g. $100$)

thx in advance

Matsch ;)

Comment: [Pillai's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_conjecture) addresses this issue.  That article gives a sense of what is known on the subject.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  In order for the MathJax formatting to take effect, you have to surround it with `$` signs.

Comment: "I know that it will never be 1" - What about $2^2-3^1=1$?

Comment: @Peter extremely large are not 2 and 1

Comment: @Interested I assume a and b integers. Suggest to edit question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that $a,b\in\mathbb{N}$ we have to take $b=\lfloor a\log_3{2}\rfloor$ in order to minimise $2^a-3^b$ yet have it remain positive. This makes the expression equivalent to
$$f(a)=2^a-3^{\lfloor a\log_3{2}\rfloor}=2^a-3^{a\log_3{2}-\{a\log_3{2}\}}=2^a\left(1-\left(\frac13\right)^{\{a\log_3{2}\}}\right)$$
where $\{x\}=x-\lfloor x\rfloor$ is the fractional part of $x$. We can bound the above function by using the fact that for $x\ge0$ we have $0\le\{x\}\lt1$ hence
$$0\le f(a)\lt\frac{2^{a+1}}{3}$$
Also since $a\log_3{2}\not\in\mathbb{N}$ for any $a\in\mathbb{N}$ (as $\log_3{2}$ is irrational) we also have that $\{a\log_3{2}\}\ne0$ hence $f(a)\gt0$. Since $f(a)\in\mathbb{N}$ we then have the strict bounds
$$1\le f(a)\le\left\lfloor\frac{2^{a+1}}{3}\right\rfloor$$
I expect that $f(a)$ is uniformly distributed within the above range for large $a$ (as one would expect $\{a\log_3{2}\}$ to be a random number within $(0,1)$) and hence is increasingly unlikely to be a small integer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I actually thought of this logarithmic expression as well and had written some code which chose chose the power b accordingly.

Then again, wouldn't that contradict the Pillai's conjecture that lulu pointed out above?
It states that there are only finitely many perfect powers with difference n. However, as you pointed out, the logarithm is a normal number so only the probability should decrease but be >0 at all times.
Maybe it's just that a converging probability (towards zero) can result in a finite amount of incidents, which I find hard to wrap my head around.